# TCard class does not have public OnShow and OnHide events

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney

In a Delphi 10.4 VCL Application, `TCard` (as container-item of `TCardPanel`) does not have public `OnShow` and `OnHide` events (like `TTabSheet` has).

Therefore, the `TCard.OnEnter` event-handler is NOT triggered when a specific `TCard` is ACTIVATED. The `TCard.OnEnter` event-handler is triggered ONLY when e.g. clicking on a control on the `TCard`.

Example code:

```
CardPanel1.ActiveCard := Card2;
```

In this case, the `TCard.OnEnter` event is NOT triggered!

Is it possible to upgrade the `TCard` class with public `OnShow` and `OnHide` events? Or is it possible to simulate those events?

Comment: Can't you just use the OnCardChange event of the TCardPanel?

Comment: @UweRaabe I have tried to use the OnCardChange event of the TCardPanel: When I try to use `PrevCard.Name` or `NextCard.Name` as string in that event-handler to identify the card then I get a run-time error. Now, I could use `NextCard.Caption` to identify the card, but that leads to "Code-Smell", as the captions could change at runtime. The CLEANEST solution would be upgrading to a `TCard.OnShow` event.

Comment: Why don't you use `ActiveCard`?

Comment: @Olivier In which context?

Comment: In the `OnCardChange`event.

Comment: @Olivier That does not make any sense, as the `OnCardChange` event-handler has already the `NextCard` and `PrevCard` parameters.

Comment: Why refer to the name? Just write `if NextCart = Card1` or `if PrevCard = Card2' or whatever makes sense here. Hard to give advice without knowing the actual use case.

Comment: @UweRaabe Uwe, you are right. I was a fool for not seeing that. If you write an answer I will accept that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the OnCardChange event of TCardPanel and compare PrevCard and/or NextCard with your actual card instances.